# Directshow Transform filter's implementation exposes data race? [solved]

Tags: c++, directshow, critical-section, data-race

I'm writing a transform filter in Directshow. I've looked at the [Transform filter implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/67a8cddc25880ebc64018e833f0bf51589fd4521/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/transfrm.cpp#L488).
They use 1 `filter_lock` for protecting filter's state and another lock called `streaming_lock` for protecting resources used in streaming thread. But in the streaming thread, the default implementation accesses the filter's state without `filter_lock`. eg: [`CTransformInputPin::Receive`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/67a8cddc25880ebc64018e833f0bf51589fd4521/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/transfrm.cpp#L754)>`CBaseInputPin::Receive`>`CTransformInputPin::CheckStreaming`>`CBasePin::IsStopped`>`accessing m_State`.
Isn't that data race if they change `m_State` in [`Pause()`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/67a8cddc25880ebc64018e833f0bf51589fd4521/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/transfrm.cpp#L488) while the filter's is in `Running_State` and checking the `m_State` in streaming thread?

P/s: I think the simple solution to avoid data race in the `m_state` is making it atomic or creating separate lock for `m_state`. This also keeps the existing logic basically unchanged. eg:

```
CTransformInputPin::CheckStreaming() {
 // check something...

 // check m_state
 {
  CAutoLock lck1(m_filter->stateLock);
  if (IsStopped()) {
   return VFW_E_WRONG_STATE;
  }
 }

}
```

```
CTransformFilter::Pause() // or Stop(), Run()
{
 CAutoLock lck(&m_csFilter);
 // logic....
 
 // when need to set m_state
 {
  CAutoLock lck1(stateLock);
  m_State = State_Paused;
 }
}
```

Update: It seems that Windows will guarantee atomic access to word/dword-sized variables like `m_state`. So it is now a relief to me.

Comment: The purpose of a lock is to make sure the object cannot be in an inconsistent state.  When there is a single variable like this, there is no possibility  for failure.  Accessing `m_State` will be atomic.  You'll either get the old value or the new value, but you can't get an inconsistent value.

Comment: @TimRoberts I read some posts they said that plain C/C++ variable like ``m_state`` is not atomic, just some architectures will guarantee it atomic but not all.

Comment: Technically true, but since this code is very specific for WIndows, and Windows only runs on x86/x64 and ARM, they don't have to worry about that.  It's worth pointing out that DirectShow was originally written in 1993.  It has survived nearly three decades of EXTENSIVE practical use.  I'm not saying it's error-free, but it is very nearly so.